# Javascript - return a value from a function called elsewhere

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function

The title of this question is not very clear but I cannot explain what I am asking without providing some code.

I am making a page which submits reports (which are arrays) using AJAX. I have functions stored in a library which submit the array to the PHP page that look like this:

```
function saveReport(params)
{
    var url="reports/save.php";

        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp==null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
        xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlHttp.send(params);

}

function stateChanged() 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        if (xmlHttp.responseText == 'complete')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

(I don't believe the GetXmlHttpObject() function is relevant to the question)

I would like to be able to call the saveReport() from my page like this

```
success = saveReport(params);
if (success == true)
{
    alert('success');
}
else
{
    alert('failure');
}
```

So the function saveReport() needs to return a value which is returned from the function stateChanged() when it is called so that the page that called saveReport() can then decide what to do - which may be a different on different pages. Is there any way of doing this?

I realise that it may be impossible the way I am trying but is there something I can do to the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're rolling your own Ajax helper?

In this situation you're going to need a callback function to be fired when the server has responded so that you can do something with the response, whether it be a success or fail.

Obviously, you can use something like [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) but that might be overkill for something this simple.

You could try one of the many micro Ajax libraries at http://microjs.com/#ajax to achieve what you're after.

Comment: I had not discovered this. I used anonymous functions which are passed to the function which uses jquery and these are called on success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it like that because the request doesn't block (it's asynchronous). What you'll have to do is use a callback the same way you have your `stateChanged()` set as the callback function for `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange`.

You can make a new function that handles the results and call that from the `stateChanged()`, passing `true` or `false` as its parameter to indicate success.

```
function stateChanged() 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        saveReportFinished(xmlHttp.responseText == 'complete');
    }
    else{
        saveReportFinished(false); 
    }
}

function saveReportFinished(success) {
    if (success == true)
    {
        alert('success');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('failure');
    }
}
```

Technically you could just combine all of this into `stateChanged()`, but I think it's cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a couple problems here:

1) Async operations cause trouble with function returns, since the function will finish firing before the async response comes back. 
2) A function will only return what you tell it to, so to get a function to return the result of another function, you'd need to do something like this: `return stateChanged( args )`

The solution to 1) is to use a callback, like so:

```
function saveReport( params, callback ){
...
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    stateChanged( callback );
};
```

Run the callback inside stateChanged()...

```
function stateChanged( callback ){
...
callback( true );
...
callback( false );
```

Then pass the callback like so:

```
saveReport( params, function( boolean ){
    if( boolean )
        alert('success');
    else
        alert('failure');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
success = saveReport(stateChanged());
if (success == true) {
    alert('success');
} else {
    alert('failure');
}
```